# how to stop the update of the widget android when I turn off the screen?

Tags: android, widget, alarmmanager, powermanager

i'm creating an application with widget. The widget is updated every 10 seconds through AlarmManager, but I would that the AlarmManager stops when the screen is off, to prevent a possible battery drain. How can I do? I tried using PowerManager but without success. 
I have implemented the AlarmManager in WidgetProvider, and through broadcast calls the class WidgetReceiver, which updates the values

-WIDGET PROVIDER:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, 1000 * 5, update(context));
}

public static PendingIntent update(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.aaa.intent.action.UPDATE_TIME");
    if (service == null) {
        service = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
    return service;
}
```

-WIDGET RECEIVER:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("com.gabriele.intent.action.UPDATE_TIME")) {
        updateWidget(context);
    }

}

private void updateWidget(Context context) {

    update my widget
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just checking whether the screen is on when you trigger the alarm?

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
if (pm.isScreenOn()) {
    // schedule the alarm
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this will turn off your alarm when the screen's off:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // If the alarm has been set, cancel it.
    if (alarmMgr!= null) {
        alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
    }
}
```

If you want it to start up again when the screen turns back on, you'll need to add corresponding code in onResume.

**EDIT**

Whoops, this will turn off your alarm whenever the activity was paused. Better would be to combine this with the other answer like so:

```
PowerManager pm;

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (pm==null) {
        pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    }
    // If the alarm has been set AND the screen is off
    if (alarmMgr!= null && !pm.isScreenOn()) {
        alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I can not implement this, because I am in class WidgetProvider